# A function to be concave

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

$f(t)={\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{d}(1+tb_{j})^{\alpha}}$ is my function.

Here, the statement says :

> If $\alpha\leq\frac{1}{d}$, all $b_{j}>0$, and $t\in[0,1]$, then $f(t)={\displaystyle
>  \prod_{j=1}^{d}(1+tb_{j})^{\alpha}}$ is concave.

I don't know how I can describe this. I know the definition of concavity
which is here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

My friend said it is all about 'sub-linearlity' I don't know what
this is. Thanks in advance.

My guess : $(1+tb)^{\alpha}$ is concave when $\alpha<1$. Is this related to this problem?

Comment: $f$ has $d$ roots, at $t_i=-1/b_i$, it can't be concave.

Comment: @DanielBeale I'm sorry but I put more conditions on my question.